# In PlayN, what size should I set for the screen to my game?

Tags: android, playn

**TL;DR Version of Question:**

For a portrait-oriented smartphone game that occupies the full screen with a 500x500 unit board at center, what should the values be for `screenWidth` and `screenHeight` in the following line of code?

```
graphics().setSize(screenWidth, screenHeight);
```

---

**Extended Version of Question:**

To simplify, assume my game is a board game with a square board at the center of the screen. These are the parameters I'm trying to work within:

- Ultimately, I'm targeting mobile phones, but I plan to beta test my
  device as a HTML5 web app (hence the appeal of PlayN). I want the web
  app dimensions to be the same as the mobile app.
- I want the orientation to be portrait.
- The board will be 500x500 units. In my pygame prototype, I just mapped the units to screen pixels. But looking at the [Android Screen Support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) docs, I realized I need to put a little more thought into this approach.
- I'd like the game board at the center of the screen. Since orientation will be portrait, I expect it to more-or-less fill in the screen horizontally. The additional vertical real estate will be used for game information, but it will be pretty minimal so I have some flexibility here.

I suppose this is a more general game-dev/geometry question. I haven't quite wrapped my head around the concept of [density-independent pixels](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#terms) yet, so while I work on that, I thought I'd put this out there, as it seems like a pretty fundamental question.

A few references I've consulted so far:

- [Android Screen Support Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)
- [PlayN Code Sample](http://playn-2011.appspot.com/slides/index.html#19) (Google Presentation Slide)
- [PlayN-Sample Cute Game Source](http://code.google.com/p/playn-samples/source/browse/cute/core/src/main/java/playn/sample/cute/core/CuteGame.java)

Comment: Did you find any generic way to fit the game screen into almost any screen size for android? I am trying it in many ways, it blurs when you scale.. please let us know if you could figure out something.

Comment: @Rockcollins I'm still focused on core/HTML development at present. Hope to move on to Android within next couple weeks. I'll update this question if I discover anything helpful.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. We are mainly focused on mobile apps first. So we will also keep updating here.

Comment: Blury means you need additional resources...